# OpenGL shader ignore texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shader, awesomium

I have recently implemented Awesomium into a OpenGL application.
When I load Awesomium in to a texture OpenGL includes it in its shading process regardless of whether I draw the texture onto a surface or not.

I am trying to trace down the line of code that is processing the texture into the shaders, is there a specific function OpenGL uses to access all textures or a way to tell OpenGL to ignore the texture?

Update texture block

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, SkypeHUD);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, AwesomiumW, AwesomiumH, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->buffer());
```

Create texture block

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, SkypeHUD);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Drawing the scene without the texture being loaded: http://puu.sh/2bVTV
Drawing the scene after I have loaded the texture: http://puu.sh/2bVUb

You can see it blending the google texture in over the others.

Answer (score 0):

Texture enable/disable should be controlled by the shader code, not some client binding state. Anyway, you most likely use several texture units (glActiveTexture); the texture binding is individual to each unit, so you'll have to do some leg work and unbind textures from each unit if you want to go this route.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I seem to be making progress :D !